# Shorthand for Int32 literals in Julia

Tags: julia, int32

I use lots of `Int32`s in my code because I have some large arrays of those. But for some `x::Int32` we have `typeof(x+1) == Int64` since numeric literals are `Int64` by default (I have to use 64bit Julia to handle my arrays). The problem is, if I have some function `f(x::Int32)` then `f(x+1)` will method error. I don't want to implement a `f(x::Int64) = f(convert(Int32, x))` for almost every function and want to use concrete types for type stability. Currently, I simply have expressions like `x + Int32(1)` all over my code which looks really cluttered. For other types we have shorthands, i.e., `1.f0` gives me a `Float32` and `big"1"` a `BigInt`. Is there something similar for `Int32`?

Comment: Can't you just do your scalar arithmetic in `Int64`, and let them be auto-converted to `Int32` when you write them to your arrays? Also, you can define `f` as `f(x::Integer)`, it does not harm performance at all.

Comment: Fair. That would be possible. But I also like that something like `update!(somecollection, index::Int64, value::Int32)` (simplified example) helps against confusing the parameters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you explicitly mention the `big_str` macro (`big""`) you can easily define a similar macro for Int32 ([the same way the uint128_str and int128_str is defined](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/d8c225007498a68d1a1c9f3229d0dbc11b98f0cf/base/int.jl#L734)):

```
macro i32_str(s)
    parse(Int32, s)
end
```

```
julia> typeof(i32"1")
Int32
```

this might still clutter your code too much so alternatively you could exploit that a number followed by a name is multiplication:

```
struct i32 end

(*)(n, ::Type{i32}) = Int32(n)
```

```
julia> typeof(1i32)
Int32
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make a macro to replace every literal integer with an `Int32`, a bit like what [ChangePrecision.jl](https://github.com/stevengj/ChangePrecision.jl) does for floats. A very quick first attempt is:

```
julia> macro literal32(ex)
         esc(literal32(ex))
       end;

julia> literal32(ex::Expr) = Expr(ex.head, literal32.(ex.args)...);

julia> literal32(i::Int) = Int32(i);

julia> literal32(z) = z;  # ignore Symbol, literal floats, etc.

julia> @literal32 [1,2] .+ 3
2-element Vector{Int32}:
 4
 5

julia> @literal32 function fun(x::AbstractVector)
         x[1] + 2  # both 1 and 2 are changed
       end
fun (generic function with 1 method)

julia> fun(Int32[3,4]) |> typeof
Int32
```

One place this may have unexpected consequences is literal type parameters:

```
julia> @literal32([1,2,3]) isa Array{Int32,1}
true

julia> @literal32 [1,2,3] isa Array{Int32,1}
false
```

Another is that `x^2` will not use `Base.literal_pow`, e.g. `@literal32 Meta.@lower pi^2`.

Answer (score 1):

What if you say:

```
# Or, a::Int32 = 1
julia> a = Int32(1)
1

julia> b::Int32 = a+2
3

julia> typeof(b)
Int32

julia> f(b)
...
```

Comment: Or e.g. `const i1 = Int32(1)` and the same pattern for any other constant value you would want to use like `i2` etc.. In this way you need only to type one extra `i` and also it is visually explicit that you are using `Int32` values.

Comment: Oh, I absolutely haven't thought about defining a global constant! Since `1` is the by far most frequent literal, this would actually work very well.